# Golang память переменные

Tags: golang

Объясните пожалуйста момент с памятью, первый вариант потребляет 7МБ памяти, а второй 0,9МБ. Что происходит с переменной `v`, почему то мне казалось что первый вариант должен наоборот меньше потреблять.

1 вариант

```
package main

type comm struct {
    Id int
    Text string
}

func (c *comm) getText() string  {
    return c.Text
}

func (c *comm) getId() int  {
    return c.Id
}



func main()  {

    var i int
    var v *comm

    for{
        i++
        v = &comm{i, "Привет"}

        println(v.getId())
    }
}
```

2 вариант

```
func main()  {

    var i int

    for{
        i++
        v: = &comm{i, "Привет"}

        println(v.getId())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В первом случае структуры создаются в куче (heap), а во втором - на стеке. Вот и разница.

То что попадает в кучу, живёт там пока не придёт уборщик мусора и в памяти некоторое время может находиться более одной структуры. А в стеке один раз выделяется нужный размер памяти и далее она переиспользуется для всех структур, которые вы создаёте в цикле for.

Чтобы посмотреть, где создалась переменная, можно воспользоваться escape анализом (escape analysis).

Для первого варианта он говорит, что ссылка утекает в кучу (`&comm literal escapes to heap`):

```
# go build -gcflags "-m" test.go
# command-line-arguments
.test.go:8:6: can inline (*comm).getText
.test.go:12:6: can inline (*comm).getId
.test.go:27:24: inlining call to (*comm).getId
.test.go:8:7: leaking param: c to result ~r0 level=1
.test.go:12:7: c does not escape
.test.go:25:13: &comm literal escapes to heap
```

А для второго, что ничего не утекает (`&comm literal does not escape`):

```
# go build -gcflags "-m" test.go
# command-line-arguments
.test.go:8:6: can inline (*comm).getText
.test.go:12:6: can inline (*comm).getId
.test.go:25:24: inlining call to (*comm).getId
.test.go:8:7: leaking param: c to result ~r0 level=1
.test.go:12:7: c does not escape
.test.go:23:14: &comm literal does not escape
```

---

Но, обратите внимание, что в FAQ есть такой вопрос:

[How do I know whether a variable is allocated on the heap or the stack?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#stack_or_heap)

где они вообще не рекомендуют задаваться этим вопросом, т.к. всё должно работать достаточно быстро в любом случае.

Comment: Получается, глобальные переменные всегда используют кучу, а переменные используемые в одной итерации к примеру, стоит объявлять внутри цикла чтобы использовать стек?

Comment: @DenKapone Глобальные, естественно в куче. Но это вообще отдельный случай, т.к. ваша переменная не глобальная - у неё область видимости функция main. Вообще, правило простое - чем уже область видимости переменной, тем лучше. Это и для компилятора лучше, т.к. он может применить некоторые дополнительные оптимизации, и для программиста, т.к. легче с этим потом разбираться.

Comment: @DenKapone И да, тут нет никакой гарантии, что созданное что-то внутри цикла обязательно будет на стеке. Это уж как решит компилятор. Если вы увеличите размер свой структуры до нескольких мегабайт (для примера), то и во втором случае скорее всего структура будет создаваться в куче.